# How to make input function on Max_bars_back

Tags: pine-script

I want to get input function on the max_bars_back function. Due to heavy script everytime I get an limit exceeded error which can be resolved in case of I set lower max_bars_back=1000.

Instead of going into the script I just setup input option on indicator settings menu. I'm trying to put input function as follows:

```
     indicator('Zee Screener v2', overlay=true, max_bars_back = input.int(5000), title = 
     "MaxBarBack")
```

unfortunately it gives me an error

```
     Cannot call 'indicator' with argument 'max_bars_back'='call 'input.int' (input 
     int)'. An argument of 'input int' type was used but a 'const int' is expected.
```

Due to lack of knowledge of the pine script I'm unable to find solution as to how to put input function. Grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an input function for that. As the error message tells you, it expects a `const`. That means, its value must be known before the script starts its execution.

Adding `max_bars_back` to improve performance is almost never the right thing to do. The problem probably lies somewhere within your code but without seeing it, it is difficult to help you.

I would suggest you have a look at [this](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-optimize-pine-code) action plan to see if you can improve the performance programmatically or upgrade your subscription plan.

Comment: I've got your point & totally agree. Thanks for the response